# not able to read input file content using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i am using phone gap to read input file content as follows

```
<input type="file"  id="sendFile" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
```

in my java script i am reading it as follows , this function gets called once the 
device is ready

```
function readImage() {



    var fileInput = document.getElementById('sendFile');
    var tfile = fileInput.files[0];
    var FR= new FileReader();



    FR.onloadend = function(e) {

    console.log("success");
    }       

    FR.readAsDataURL(tfile);

}
```

and i am getting following error , i have no idea why its there and how to resolve it

> file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1064 : processMessage
>   failed: Error: TypeError: Result of expression
>   'this._realReader.readAsDataURL' [undefined] is not a function.

i am using `android 2.2.1` version

note**

it works with `fileEntry` object but it doesnt work with input tag , i hope anyone has a solution for this

Comment: Do device ready when you call function. Make sure, add event deviceready when you phonegap api

Comment: i call tht function once the device is ready only

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the browser in android 2.x does not fully implement the html5 file api.

If you look at the attributes of the file object you get from the file input on android 2, some are missing like lastModifiedDate and most of the functions are also not there.

Running the same code in an android 4.2.2 device works perfectly :(

Unfortunatly, to get a file object from the file input, you do not rely on a phonegap function but on the support of the html5 file api of the default browser on your device.

It seems that on android the file api is [only supported starting with version 3.x](http://mobilehtml5.org/)

If you only want to support images, you could use the 
[Phonegap camera plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) and set Camera.sourceType to Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY to select a picture from the album.